# Uk visa for Egyptians

Tags: visas, uk, repeat-visits, egyptian-citizens

My mother in law took her visit visa for 6 months from October to March 2019. But her husband got a heart attack so we had to apply for another visa for her from January till July 2019.

I am going to have a huge operation by October, and I need her to be with me for my two kids. Specially that my husband works in another city so I don’t have any support or help with my kids.

Can I apply for another 3 months for her starting from September till December 2019 or she can’t enter the country two times in the same year???

Comment: How long has your mother actually spent in the UK? If she was in the country from January to July and she applies to come for another three months, I think there's a high chance that the visa will be rejected on the grounds that it looks like she's effectively trying to live in the UK by making repeated visits.

Comment: Also UKVI has been known to consider childcare as work, even within a family by a close relative. If you’re going to have a huge operation and you have childcare needs, you should talk to your medical team about the support that may be available. Just an opinion, but I agree with David Richerby’s comment that a second visa application with a gap of only 3 months after a visit lasting 6 is likely to be refused. The typical guide is to spend at least as long out of the country as in it.

Answer (score 1):

Can she apply? Yes.

Can she enter the UK twice in one year? Possibly. There is no Immigration Rule explicitly stating the number of visits/days permitted. However, applicants do have to demonstrate they are a genuine visitor: V 4.2(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

If your mother has already spent 6 months in the UK in 2019, she’ll likely have a hard time demonstrating that she is a genuine visitor. IMHO she’d be risking a refusal trying to return so soon after such a long visit. If her visit was less than 6 months she may have a better chance of approval, assuming she can show she has strong ties to home.